# Moving WooCommerce from testing to production breaks checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I just moved bubbagummy.com.au/testing to bubbagummy.com.au 
This is a Wordpress install, with WooCommerce plugin.

After I moved it, I did the typical searchreplacedb.php thing, and to make the database entries match the new location. Everything works on the site.

My only problem, is that when I go to checkout, fill in the details, etc, the checkout submits to the same page. No feedback, no success page... it just loads the checkout page again.

I cannot find a solution to this anywhere. Incredibly frustrating.

Any help would be great.

Comment: bubbagummy.com.au is just loading a folder index so I'm not sure which is the live site in order to test it. Are you seeing any JS errors in your console? The folder index may be the problem, but can you put your payment processor into any kind of testing mode so I don't have to purchase anything.

Comment: try it again. I was moving directories to see if it fixed it. All back to how I mentioned

Comment: @helgatheviking a test credit card is 4242424242424242

Comment: Can you check out via other methods? I'm seeing one error in the console from Striper. The WP forums's suggest that Striper has been forked and re-written. I would check that out... or better still try the official [WooCommerce Stripe](http://www.woothemes.com/products/stripe/) extension.

Comment: your form action is "checkout" so you need to check the php code to see whats going out ($_POST)

Comment: So, the end-points aren't being appended to the URL during checkout, so it doesn't go to the success page. Also, there are no errors, and the order is successful in the backend.